# Mui DatePicker change date format

Tags: html, css, reactjs, date, material-ui

I am trying to customise the mui DatePicker. I want the date format to be as follows: Day, DD Month.
example: Monday, 10 September
here is my code:

```
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} locale={frLocale}>
    <Stack spacing={3}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={calendarTheme}>
        <DatePicker
          disabled={false}
          //the current format
          inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
          leftArrowButtonText={t("notification.previous_month")}
          rightArrowButtonText={t("notification.next_month")}
          minDate={today}
          InputProps={{
            classes: {
              notchedOutline: classes.noBorder,
              root: classes.reverse,
            },
          }}
          components={{
            OpenPickerIcon: Table,
            SwitchViewIcon: ArrowDown,
          }}
          value={value}
          onChange={handlechange}
          renderInput={(params: any) => (
            <TextField
              style={{
                color: "red",
              }}
              {...params}
            />
          )}
        />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Stack>
  </LocalizationProvider>
```

[image: The current format]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use fromat like `format="EEEE, MM MMMM"`:

```
<DesktopDatePicker
      label="Date desktop"
      inputFormat="EEEE, MM MMMM"
      openTo={"day"}
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    />
```

[image: Edit MaterialUIPickers Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: @Ah_Ch_97 updated answer! Please check it again.

Comment: If it is possible please share this part of your code into the codesandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/materialuipickers-material-demo-forked-7meb2
I used your proposed solution in this official documentation code sample and I got the same problem the day is not well formated

Comment: @Ah_Ch_97 Please check the answer again!

Comment: in fact "EEEE, MM MMMM" solved the problem thank you and please update the answer